# Devise - ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError when sending reset password instructions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I overrode find_first_by_auth_conditions method to search for email or username, as provided by the wiki:

```
def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
    conditions = warden_conditions.dup
    if login = conditions.delete(:login)
      where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).first
    else
      where(conditions).first
    end
  end
```

But when I try to reset password I get:

```
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError
```

in this line:

```
where(conditions).first
```

I am using devise_parameter_sanitizer in my Application_controller:

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :username, :password_confirmation}
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:username, :password, :login, :remember_me) }
  end
```

I am using Devise 3.4.1 and Rails 4.1.7.

Comment: does your `devise.rb` include `config.authentication_keys` ?

Comment: Yes, config.authentication_keys = [ :login ]

Comment: is it rails 4 ? did you use `devise_parameter_sanitizer` to permit params ?

Comment: It is Rails 4.1.7. Yes, I define devise_parameter_sanitizer in my application controller, but it seems password confirmation does not use them. I updated my answer with this info.

Answer (score 4):

```
  def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
    conditions = warden_conditions.dup
    if login = conditions.delete(:login)
      where(conditions).where(["lower(inn) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).first
    else
      conditions.permit! if conditions.class.to_s == "ActionController::Parameters"
      where(conditions).first
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to update the `configure_permitted_parameters`:

```
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:login, :username, :email, :password, :remember_me) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password) }
  end
```

and make sure that user model has:

```
attr_accessor :login
```

Comment: I added devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) but it didn't work. It seems /users/password devise post action does not understand this.

Comment: I did, the logs only show this error in Devise::PasswordsController#create

Comment: actually this seems a bug in devise. I don't know if this should work `prepend_before_filter :allow_params_authentication!` . If not then overriding the controller is your only option.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem today. So I googled it and finally found a solution:

The idea is "[Do not pass down 'ActionController::Parameters' to outside the controller](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/pull/3162)"

I am sure your `self.find_first_by_auth_conditions` code is coming from [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address#for-activerecord). But seems after strong_parameters gem [upgrade](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters/compare/5199f84...0d21cc58167df513ee9581170c862901697b3827#diff-f9b2a65e6aa933a12946fe7e4a32c9c8L76). It breaks this example code... Before the dup method's result is a new hash. But currently it still a instance of Parameters

The solution I use is either to_h or permit! your params in this method.
`conditions = warden_conditions.dup.permit!`

Answer (score 0):

I had to override Devise::PasswordsController and add the permit! keyword to resource_params:

```
   def create
        self.resource = resource_class.send_reset_password_instructions(resource_params.permit!)
        yield resource if block_given?

        if successfully_sent?(resource)
          respond_with({}, location: after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for(resource_name))
        else
          respond_with(resource)
        end
    end
```

But I dont think this is the best way possible to handle this. I hope there is a better answer.